# Unable to give string as first parameter in dictionary Acumatica 2019R2 (Device hub print related)

Tags: acumatica

I am unable to give a `string` as the first parameter in dictionary Acumatica 2019R2

```
public void PrintReportInDeviceHub(string reportID, Dictionary<string, string> parametersDictionary, string printerName, int? branchID)
{
    Dictionary<string, PXReportRequiredException> reportsToPrint = new Dictionary<string, PXReportRequiredException>();
    PrintParameters filter = new PrintParameters();
    filter.PrintWithDeviceHub = true;
    filter.DefinePrinterManually = true;
    filter.PrinterName = printerName;

    reportsToPrint = PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.AssignPrintJobToPrinter(reportsToPrint, parametersDictionary, filter, new NotificationUtility(this.Base).SearchPrinter, CRNotificationSource.BAccount, reportID, reportID, branchID);

    if (reportsToPrint != null)
    {
        PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.CreatePrintJobGroups(reportsToPrint);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Thank you Gabriel.
I am not getting any error.

Problem is 'reportsToPrint'  count  is 0

Answer (score 0):

In order to print using device hub I followed the below code and it should work:

```
Dictionary<string, string> reportParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// Add Report Parameters

PrintSettings printerSettings = new PrintSettings()
{
    PrintWithDeviceHub = true,
    DefinePrinterManually = true,
    PrinterID = , //Set the printer id of the printer you want to use
    NumberOfCopies = 1
};

PXReportRequiredException reportToPrint = null;
reportToPrint = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(reportToPrint,
    /* ReportID */, reportParams);

SMPrintJobMaint.CreatePrintJobGroup(printerSettings, deliveryListReport. "Printing Report");
```